# How to get more gold after Khrumbul-dun?

Tags: dragon-quest-builders-2

In Khrumbul-dun I got daily amounts of metal. This haul I took over to the Isle of Awakening. But as gold was the last one and I was going on with the story and they stopped bringing up metals for me.

How can I get easily gold now? Because mining it is kinda hard as the blocks are hard to break. Should I have waited longer to progress the story and get more days with mining hauls this way?

Comment: Hello. I have just finished this island.
Can you explain why do you need more gold ? Is it to complete the island or just to build fancy stuff ?
In the first case, I'm afraid that there is no other solution than mining ore (but you shouldn't need that much anyway).
In the second case, there should be an explorer shore that you can go to and mine.

Comment: Second. And yeah, there is an explorers shore, but mining gold in particular is a pain in the ass as the blocks are so hard to break. I ask myself if I should've waited some more days to get more gold from the daily accumulation.

Comment: Ok, then you might need to wait on the next Hammer upgrade. Don't have it yet so I don't know if it makes a difference (and I don't want to spoil myself).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Khrumbul-dun, you get gold by mining. But...late in the game...

-- SPOILERS FOLLOW --

> In Malhala, you can get gold from *Huge Horns*, *Big Bad Bottom Teeth*, and *Titanic Top Teeth* at the *Forbidden Altar*. Also, There's an explorer's shore called **Coral Cay** which, after completing the objectives, gives you infinite gold